# React-native doesn't reload ios application in simulator

Tags: ios, reactjs, native, reload, watchman

i have issue with reloading app,

react-native-cli: 1.2.0
react-native: 0.37.0
watchman: 4.7.0

index.ios.js file.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactNative, {View,Text} from 'react-native';
import Header  from './src/components/header';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Header headerText={'Products '}/>
            <Text>Test</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

ReactNative.AppRegistry.registerComponent('ditrack', ()=> App);
```

> then run command react-native run-ios. 
>   App simulator loaded but don't update any changes in code for ex.

```
 <Text>Test</Text> to <Text> OTHER Test</Text>
```

> I already reviewed several issues in stackoverflow and github but it did't helped me

Comment: Instead of **<Text>Test</Text>**, try this way: **<Text>{this.state.textToShow}</Text>**. Then you must set the state you want react to render like this: **this.setState({ textToShow: 'what Ever' });**
React is watching the state to realize whether it has to render or not.

Comment: Do you mean simulator is not reloading when you update your code automatically? if so, you should press Cmd+D which will open up debug menu and there select either enable live reload or enable hot reload.

Comment: Thank you for reply, Even if i activate hot reload or reload by myself with CMD + R

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca  it doesn't help  :-(  I think it because of Watchman and Packager

Comment: @askar for example i update some code in index.ios.js file and then i want see my update in simulator but it doesn't reload with my new changes if reload by self it looks like it doesn't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finded solution. I did `sudo pkill -9 -x fseventsd` and then run command `react-native start` with sudo. `sudo react-native start`